# Using FabricJS like -webkit-filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fabricjs

I could not really find an answer online, so here I go: I want to use FabricJS as a replacement for -webkit-filter, as I have a chain of filters that I like to use on a background image of a div on my webpage. My question now is: how to achieve this with FabricJS? The background-image is set on a div by the CSS rule background-image: url(/path/to/img) and I just want to apply some FabricJS image filters to the image before it is rendered as a background for the div. Is this possible? And if it is, how would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would do the following, using fabric and JQuery:

- Create a fabric canvas element with image width & height.
- Insert original image into canvas.
- Apply filters to image.
- Declare a variable `var image_with_filters;`
- Assign canvas content to this variable with `image_with_filters = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.8);` (or some image format and parameters).
- Apply this variable to div background `$('#your_div').css('backgroundImage','url('+image_with_filters+')');`
- Try it.

Regards.